# Nuxt Generate dynamic routes from the store

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using `nuxt.js` and now need to generate my dynamic pages by running `npm run generate`. However my list items needed to make dynamic items are stored in the store, so I need to map over them somehow so the generate can make the routes for them

How can I access the store in my `nuxt.config.js`?

```js
generate: {
  dir: 'wwwroot', //override the default generation dir to create everything straight in wwwroot
  routes() {
    let vdc = this.$store.vdcServers.map(server => `/virtual-data-centres/${server.slug}`);
    return Promise.all([vdc]).then(values => {
      return values.join().split(',');
    })
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
 ERROR  Could not resolve routes                                                                        
 FATAL  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$store')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, you cannot access the store from that place. Maybe with some [`hooks`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-hooks#list-of-hooks)? I doubt.
Meanwhile, if you have your elements available in your store you should be able to find them back by making a quick axios call or like I think.

[This kind](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate#function-with-a-callback) of approach is totally fine

```js
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  generate: {
    routes(callback) {
      axios
        .get('https://my-api/users')
        .then(res => {
          const routes = res.data.map(user => {
            return '/users/' + user.id
          })
          callback(null, routes)
        })
        .catch(callback)
    }
  }
}
```

It may be a bit of code duplication, meanwhile, it's still the simplest way to go.
Otherwise, you could try to persist it to some localStorage or any similar solution, to have it both in Vuex and during your generation.

Comment: I thought so..thanks